# What are differnces between the production mode and the development mode in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I know how to set it up and how to ready it by the env function. But what is the difference between these two options? What exacly changes?

Comment: What do you want to change? Normally it's stuff like not wanting to have ssl enabled in development but yeah go for it in production

Comment: Right now I am learning and I want to get the basic knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `production` or `development` mode, these are environment names that you can use to turn certain testing features on or off in different places.

There is however also the `APP_DEBUG` option in your `.env` file. This option depicts if information about errors is shown to the user. You should always set this to `false` when deploying to a live server. Setting debug on might expose database passwords or display your code to users.

Comment: There is a `production` mode, sort of. https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/195dba7ea2a68d3a49593d0de0df73c12a59fc72/src/Illuminate/Console/ConfirmableTrait.php#L51 https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/71577f1ba2ee253a263a6314ec8fd82179c6d252/tests/Foundation/FoundationApplicationTest.php#L198

Comment: Well, maybe I did not make myself clear. I mean APP_ENV=local and APP_ENV=production.

Answer (score 0):

I mean APP_ENV=local and APP_ENV=production